# You know who I am, you know me best

Tags: riddle

I'm stuck on a riddle and need help! Here's the riddle:

> You know who I am
>   you know me best
>   a persona that you created
>   that you haven't quite laid to rest

What am I?

According to the hints, it is a scrabble segment - it comes in a series of a few words.
I can't put my finger on it but i know it isn't a nightmare or dream.

Comment: Hi, welcome to PSE! Looks like this riddle comes from another place. Please add the source of this puzzle.

Comment: Also, this doesn't seem specific enough as a puzzle. Off the top, I can think of quite a few potential answers to this riddle that all seem to satisfy the conditions.

Answer (score 6):

Since the riddle is part of a “scrabble segment,” I believe the answer might be

> **ego**, due to the word’s short length

You know who I am
you know me best

> While your ego may show to other people through your actions, you are the one that knows it the best i.e. what makes it tic

a persona that you created
that you haven't quite laid to rest

> This could refer to [Sigmund Freud’s Id, superego, and ego theory](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Id,_ego_and_super-ego), which postulates that the ego is a self-constructed persona that acts as an arbiter between the two other extreme desires. Of course, you can never lay the ego to rest because it is needed to keep your inner desires in check.

Answer (score 5):

> An imaginary friend.
>
>  You created them, only you can get rid of them, you know them best because its in your head.

Answer (score 2):

> The answer is **your inner voice or mind**
>
>  You created it since you have memory, and you know him because it's you.